# TFS Check-in note Fields different per user?

Tags: tfs, checkin, checkin-policy

I have a Team Project set up with custom Check-in Notes : "Ticket" and "Code Reviewer".  This is displayed to all in-house users on check-in.  However, when the one external dev tries to check in, he is presented with the default "Code Reviewer","Performance Reviewer","Security Reviewer".  I haven't found anything different between his permissioning and the in-house dev's.  Why would one person see different fields?

Comment: Is the remote dev using the same version of visual studio?

Comment: Yes - the remote dev is using 2010 Ultimate SP1.  Local devs use a combo of 2010/2012 and the custom notes show on both.

Comment: Can you get the external dev to delete the cache? C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation